# How to make Gitlab CI automatically create pipelines on every commit

Tags: gitlab-ci

Back in the days I've seen on a demo (can't recall now where) where after every push, the Gitlab CI automatically created a pipeline for this commit in an appropriate branch, but without running it automatically.

This allowed user to run pipeline on any branch without having to manually select branch from "new pipeline" button.

Can't find such information in the documentation. Perhaps it was a hack but nonetheless it worked.

Comment: Maybe they were using `when: manual`? Link here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#whenmanual